# How to inherit a templatised Base class?

Tags: c++, templates

I am new to STL. I have written a Template Base class as follows

```
template <class T>  
class Base  
{  
    public:    
    //Constructor and Destructor ..  
    Base();  
    virtual ~Base();  
    virtual foo() = 0;  
};
```

Now , I want to design my framework such that my inherited classes will be publicly derived from this class and will implement foo in their respective implementations. Problem is that I don't know how to inherit from a Template Base class ? 
Is it as below ...

```
template class<T>  
class Derived : public Base<T>  
{ 
  // Implementation of Derived constructor etc and methods ...  
};
```

or  Normal C++ way

```
class Derived : public Base  
{  
};
```

Any suggestions ?  Also, I would appreciate for any information for getting started with STL for newbies like me ...

Regards,
Atul

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The later,

```
class Derived : public Base
```

will **not** work, because `Base` is not a class, it's a class template. Than it depends on whether `Derived` should be a template or whether it should inherit particular instance of `Base`:

- Template:

  ```
  template<typename T>
  class Derived : public Base<T>
  ```
- Non-template:

  ```
  class Derived : public Base<Something>
  ```

  (where `Something` is some concrete type like `int` or `char *` or `std::string`)

Comment: Thanks Jan, My derived classes are Template classes as well.

Comment: @Jane, it can be the 3rd way also:`template<typename T>
class Derived : public Base<Something>`

Answer (score 1):

Either

```
template class<T>  
class Derived : public Base<T>  
{ };
```

if you want `Derived` to work with `Base<>`s of any type.

Or

```
class Derived : public Base<SomeSpecificType>
{ };
```

if you want `Derived` to only work with a specific type of `Base<>`.

Comment: Thanks, ildjarn, Any ideas as to where I will be getting more and simple examples for starting my encounter with STL meta programing ?

Comment: @Atul : For online resources, the [Comeau template FAQ](http://www.comeaucomputing.com/techtalk/templates/) and [C++ FAQ Lite chapter on templates](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/templates.html) are decent. I don't really know of any *light-reading* books on templates, but if you want to jump in the deep end then there's [Modern C++ Design](http://www.amazon.com/dp/0201704315/) and [C++ Template Metaprogramming](http://www.amazon.com/dp/0321227255/).

Answer (score 0):

Your second example is the way to go.

```
template class<T>   
public Base<T>   
{    // Implementation of Base constructor etc and methods ...   
}; 


template class<T>   
class Derived : public Base<T>   
{    // Implementation of Derived constructor etc and methods ...   
public:
    Derived() : Base<T>() { } //have to construct the proper instanciation of Base

};
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the above answers, also be aware that it can be in following ways also:

```
template<typename T>
class Derived : public Base<Something>  // Something is some concrete type
```

or

```
template<typename T, typename U>
class Derived : public Base<U>
```